# How to get rid of "Designed by" in the theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I am using the business theme in Drupal 7. I was wondering how do I get rid of the "Designed by Devsaran." in the bottom right corner?

Comment: This is a very specific question to a theme not in core Drupal. You'd either be looking at a block or bit of code in a tpl file to remove it. Did you try searching the theme for any files containing 'designed by'?

Comment: Yes I looked through all the files and can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit the `page.tpl.php` file and remove the line in the footer:

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/business/tree/templates/page.tpl.php?h=7.x-1.x

Its at the bottom.

```
  <div id="copyright">
    <?php if ($footer_copyright): ?>
      <?php print $footer_copyright; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (theme_get_setting('footer_credits')): ?>
      <span class="credits"><?php print t('Designed by'); ?>  <a href="http://www.devsaran.com">Devsaran</a>.</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
```

However, it seems like there is a theme setting you can just uncheck as well, under Admin > Appearance > Business > Settings called 'Footer Credit'.

Comment: Thanks. It worked by disabling the setting in the Admin > Appearance > Business > Settings page.